# DocumentTooLarge during query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to get a large number (1 million) of documents by their object id, stored in a list `obj_ids`. So I use

```
docs = collection.find({'_id' : {'$in' : obj_ids}})
```

However, when trying to access the documents (e.g. `list(docs)`) I get

```
pymongo.errors.DocumentTooLarge: BSON document too large (19889042 bytes) - the connected server supports BSON document sizes up to 16777216 bytes.
```

which confuses me. As I understand this, the document size is 16 MB for a *single* document. But I don't think I have any document exceeding this limit:

1. I did not get this error message when inserting any of the documents in the first place.
2. This error does not show up if I chunk the ObjectIds into 2 subsets, and recombine the results later.

So if there is not some too big document in my collection, what is the error message about?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414934/program-to-merge-arrays-prints-0s-instead-of-the-actual-merged-array?noredirect=1#comment103172908_58414934

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea query'in 1 million documents, did you consider paging?

Comment: @roottraveller How is this related?

Comment: @SuleymanSah not sure what you mean by "paging". I could chunk the data as already mentioned. But that would not answer my question. (I am trying to understand the problem.)

Comment: @Feodoran GridFS. I have updated the link

Comment: @roottraveller: How does "GridFS" **explain** the error message? Also, I still don't see the connection between the linked and my question.

Comment: @roottraveller Also, I don't think GridFS is the answer, since I actually don't have any documents that need to be splitted. My question is about why I get this error despite of that fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query `{'_id' : {'$in' : obj_ids}}` is the issue, that's too large, not the documents themselves.

You'll need to refactor your approach; maybe do it in batches and join the results.

Comment: So pymongo cannot do this for me, automatically?

Comment: Afraid not. I'd be curious to know exactly why you were trying to get 1m documents in this manner; depending on what you are trying to do would dictate what strategy you should adopt.

Comment: I repeatedly need to access the same data. Its faster to do the actual querying and filtering once (there is some additional processing involved), store the object ids and then just reload based on these selected object ids.

Comment: If you're still stuck I suggest you create a new request outlining the specifics.

Comment: I had the same issue and reducing `obj_ids` solved it, thanks for that. Still, I had a hard time understading why it worked, so I thought it was worth saying it out loud. The `query` element in `find` is itself a document, which being too large (above 16mb) raises the `DocumentTooLarge` error