# Program to merge arrays prints 0s instead of the actual merged array

Tags: c++, data-structures

Program to merge two arrays into a separate third array doesn't actually do anything, despite me going through the code a couple times. Tried changing loop counters, variables, nothing seems to work. So, after I input the array sizes and elements, the merged array is just a string of zeroes for some reason.

Here's the code:

```
#include "iostream"
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[MAX],n1,i;
    int b[MAX],n2,j;
    int r[MAX],k;
    cout << "Array 1: ";
    cout << "\nEnter number of elements in the array: ";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    for (i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
        cout << "\nArray 2: ";
    cout << "\nEnter the number of elements in the array: ";
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array: ";
    for (j=0;j<n2;j++)
    {
        cin >> b[j];
    }
    //Merging the arrays
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[j])
        {
            r[k] = a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            r[k] = b[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while (i < n1)
    {
        r[k] = a[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < n2)
    {
        r[k] = b[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    cout << "\nMerged Array: \n";
    for (k=0;k<n1+n2;k++)
    {
        cout << r[k] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (i < n1 && j < n2)` -- that condition can never be true (and neither can the two following ones) since the `for` loops have modified `i` and `j`. You should learn to use a debugger to step through your code and check that it does what you expect.

Comment: `k` is not initialized to `0` and YES as pointed by @Quentin its should be a `||`

Comment: @roottraveller that's not what I'm saying though: the issue is that both indices are out-of-range from the start.

Comment: @roottraveller Whereas it's true that `k` must be initialized, the `&&` condition is correct. The OP's algorithm merges as long as there are items in both arrays. The code following the first loop copies the remainder of whichever array still has items.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=0;i<n1;i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

and

```
for (j=0;j<n2;j++)
{
    cin >> b[j];
}
```

end with `i` and `j` set to `n1` and `n2`.

You may want to reinitialize them to `0` and then proceed.

Adding `i=0;j=0;k=0;` before the while loop will help.

### Why do you need to initialize variables?

If not initialized, k will contain junk values which may not be equal to `0`.

For any value other than `0` your code will not behave the way you expect.